# Google Analytics is displaying /click instead of /event

Tags: google-analytics

I use tracking of different links by putting /event/SOME_TAG in onClick event and then I see /event/SOME_TAG in Google analytics but since the first week of March, I have started seeing /click/SOME_TAG along with /event/SOME_TAG and /event/SOME_TAG is zero since the beginning of march and /click/SOME_TAG is getting all the pageviews and related things.

What should I do to start tracking /event/SOME_TAG again?

Comment: Double check the tracking code that is recording the link (posting it here my help someone solve it for you) and check if any filters were added to the profile on or about the beginning of March.

Comment: I have checked again and I am not tracking any of the /click/ tags

Comment: I am not sure about any filter. I will look into it as it appears to be the case.

Comment: It appears to be the Filter issue. As, I don't have access to it so I cannot be 100% sure but I see that must be there.